# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ola estou batendo cabeça a alguns dias mas ainda não consegui resolver, possuo uma tag input hidden que recebe um value php conforme abaixo, porém preciso ler este value em js, mas quando leio ele me apresenta o erro acima. Poderiam me ajudar?

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="leagueName" value="<?php echo $ranking_privado_name;?>"/>
```

JS

```js
//pegando o nome da liga para incluir usuario
var liga = document.querySelector("#leagueName");
var ligaName = liga.value;

console.log(ligaName);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="leagueName" value="<?php echo $ranking_privado_name;?>"/>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Você provavelmente está tentando capturar o elemento antes dele ser carregado na página, veja mais em [DOMContentLoaded_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: Boa Tarde, eu estava tentando capturar um elemento vindo da URL antes dele ser carregado na pagina, consegui resolver, agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score -2):

Se não há outro elemento com o mesmo id, tente com getElementById. Acredito que, nesse caso, facilitaria mais. A não ser que seja estritamente necessário o uso do querySelector....

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eu tentei mas o erro permanece.

Comment: mesmo passando por exemplo, o value como value="777" ele nao recebe valor nenhum no js.

Comment: poderia colocar o código dessas páginas? Ou veja se esse artigo pode ajudá-lo: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-cannot-read-property-value-of-null#:~:text=Conclusion%20%23-,The%20%22Cannot%20read%20property%20'value'%20of%20null%22%20error,DOM%20elements%20have%20been%20declared

Answer (score -2):

Não tem nada de errado com o teu JS, o problema está na linha PHP que tu fez;

Em vez de:

```
<input type="hidden" id="leagueName" value="<?php echo $ranking_privado_name;?>">
```

Coloca:

```
<?php echo "<input type='hidden' id='leagueName' value=".$ranking_privado.">" ?>
```

Comment: Entao eu removi o codigo php e coloquei uma sring ex: value ="777", e notei que no js ele nao esta puxando o valor deste campo, mesmo sendo ou nao php. var liga = document.getElementById("leagueName");
//var ligaName = liga.value;

console.log(liga); //O resultado tem sido null